# Possible to connect second keyboard and make it programmable with shortcuts ?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a full-time programmer and have to rely on a lot of shortcuts in my IDE(in Windows). Unfortunately, remembering those shortcuts is hard. Is it possible to connect a second keyboard and assign to each key a shortcut ?

I did looked into buying a "programmable keypad", but they are rather expensive.

Comment: The second keyboard will be treated the same by Windows. So whatever keyboard you use it will behave the same. AFAIK a programmable keyboard is your only option. Except there is some SW which is able to change the input depending of which keyboard you use.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).  Take a moment and read this [thread](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=7545), as it discusses the pitfalls and how to overcome them.